# Command line to rename file using name of other file type

Tags: command-line

I have 2 files: `fileone.txt` and `filetwo.mkv`.

How can I use the command line to rename `filetwo.mkv` to `fileone.mkv`.

Comment: Specifying which OS/CLI you are using might help?!

Answer (score 1):

Just type rename:

```
rename filetwo.mkv fileone.mkv
```